# thumbs.db messing up my upload routine

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error while uploading a zip archive.

```
Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo(C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite/wp-content/themes/mytheme//styles\mytheme/Thumbs.db) [ziparchive.extractto]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-content\themes\mythem\uploader.php on line 17
```

The thing I can't quite figure is that I don't see a thumbs.db file in either the zip archive or the destination folder that was created (the upload still processes, I just get these errors).

The function is below, line 17 is commented...

```
function openZip($file_to_open) { 
    global $target;  
    $zip = new ZipArchive();  
    $x = $zip->open($file_to_open);  
    if($x === true) {  
        $zip->extractTo($target);  //this is line 17
        $zip->close();  

        unlink($file_to_open);  
    } else {  
        die("There was a problem. Please try again!");  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like just a warning. I would ignore it. I'm betting the error happens when it tried to overwrite the thumbs.db file in the extraction directory.

Alternatively, use `getNameIndex` to get a list of files, filter thumbs.db and use the second parameter of `extractTo` to filter the files.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-getnameindex.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-extractto.php

Answer (score 0):

This path is all messed up
C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite/wp-content/themes/mytheme//styles\mytheme/Thumbs.db

I guess this might be windows issue.

can you add a line above line 17 saying

```
echo $file_to_open; exit;
```

and tell us what it says when you try to upload file?

Comment: C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/myupgradefile.zip

Comment: well, i don't know how windows handles path with mixed slash and backslash characters, maybe some win user can help here.

is C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite/wp-content/themes/mytheme 
directory that exists? can apache write to it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the mangled path works, then there is a thumbs.db in the destination directory (by default a hidden file), and/or your script does not have permission to write to that file/directory. Windows is very big on spitting out "permission denied" when a file is in use by another process, rather than saying "In use by process XXX".